# ¿como podría guardar archivos en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, archivo, array

```
private int laberinto[][]={
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}};
```

tengo esta parte código para hacer un mapa de un pacman pero no quiero hacer una clase por mapa, me pueden ayudar a que solo lea cierto archivo por nivel???

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero si queires hacer un ArrayList de archivos sería así: `List<File> arregloFicheros = new ArrayList<>();` si usas java 7 o superior claro, sino sería: `List<File> arregloFicheros = new ArrayList<File>();` cada objeto que metas al array corresponderá a un nivel.

Comment: si, digamos que tengo los mapas escritos en un archivo .txt y el contenido que se guarde en un arreglo y que cada 60 pase a la siguiente fila

Comment: No te estoy entendiendo, tu tienes todos los mapas metidos a un Txt , entonces quieres que cada 60 (Caracteres, Arreglos etc) se guarden a un archivo cada vez y esos a su vez estén en un array de Files ?

Comment: mmmmmm no tengo un archivo de texto y digamos que esta escrito con 60 caracrteres de largo por 60 de ancho (osea un solo mapa), quiero el el arreglo lea ese archivo y lo almacene

Comment: Vamos, que quieres guardar esos arreglos(Fichero) en otro arreglo(Niveles) y no el File como tal entero en el arreglo(Niveles) . Para resumir: sería guardar en un arreglo(Niveles) un arreglo de dos dimensiones que contiene el "mapeado" del nivel